# Suffix Trie and Suffix Tree

Tags: java, trie, suffix-tree

I understand the difference between (Prefix) Trie, a Suffix Trie and a Suffix Tree and I am trying to write Java code for both. What is the Java representation/structure of the SuffixTrieNode and SuffixTreeNode class?

```
SuffixTrie representation:

class SuffixTrie{
   SuffixTrieNode root;

   class SuffixTrieNode{
      SuffixTrieNode[] links;
   }
}

SuffixTree representation:

class SuffixTree{
   SuffixTreeNode root;

   class SuffixTreeNode{
      SuffixTreeNode[] links;
   }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think it is completely clear what you are asking for, but you can find completed solutions for both if you google them. For example, a suffix tree implementation is found at http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-suffix-tree/

Comment: I could find implementations for suffix tree but not suffix trie. Are the structures similar for both? Basically, my question is to represent the Nodes  in a Suffix Trie and a Suffix Tree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893950/suffix-tree-and-tries-what-is-the-difference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042825/short-java-implementation-of-a-suffix-tree-and-usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generalized Suffix Tree Java Implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969448/generalized-suffix-tree-java-implementation)

Comment: Folks - thanks for commenst but those are all implementations of "SuffixTrees" not "SuffixTries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suffix trie uses a trie data structure. It is the simplest way to build a suffix tree:[Suffix tree and Tries. What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893950/suffix-tree-and-tries-what-is-the-difference).